# Regular Expressions: Special Characters and Tab Spaces

Tags: python, regex

I was testing out a function that I wrote. It is supposed to give me the count of full stops (.) in a line or string. The full stop (.) that I am interested in counting has a tab space before and after it.

Here is what I have written.

```
def Seek():
   a = '1   .   .   3   .'
   b = a.count(r'\t\.\t')
   return b
Seek()
```

However, when I test it, it returns 0. From a, there are 2 full stops (.) with both a tab space before and after it. Am I using regular expressions improperly? Represented a incorrectly? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like `a` has any tabs in it. Although you may have hit the `tab` key on your keyboard, that character would have been interpreted by the text editor as "insert a number of spaces to align with the next tab character". You need your line to look like this:

```
a = '1\t.\t.\t3\t.'
```

That should do it.

A more complete example:

```
from re import *
def Seek():
   a = '1\t.\t.\t3\t\.'
   re = compile(r'(?<=\t)\.(?=\t)');
   return len(re.findall(a))
print Seek()
```

This uses "lookahead" and "lookbehind" to match the `tab` character *without consuming it*. What does that mean? It means that when you have `\t.\t.\t`, you will actually match both the first and the second `\.`. The original expression would have matched the initial `\t\.\t` **and discarded them**. After, there would have been a `\.` with nothing in front of it, and thus no second match. The lookaround syntax is "zero width" - the expression is tested but it ends up taking no space in the final match. Thus, the code snippet I just gave returns `2`, just as you would expect.

Comment: Thanks! However, what if I wanted the total number of full stops (.) so that the value 3 returns? How would I include the last full stop that does not have a tab after it without counting or duplicating the other occurrences that have both tabs before and after?

Comment: Well you did say "has a tab before and after it"... If you don't need the tab after, you just leave out the lookbehind part of the regex: so `re = compile(r'(?<=\t)\.');` should do it - not tested, on iPhone.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Just noticed your comment 2 seconds ago.

Answer (score 0):

It will work if you replace the '\t' with a single tab key press.

Note that count only counts non-overlapping occurrences of a substring so it won't work as intended unless you use regex instead, or change your substring to only test for a tab in front of the period.

Comment: Pressing a tab key doesn't always insert the tab character - that depends entirely on the editor you are using.